# Makefile that places object files into an alternate directory (bin/)

Tags: beginner, makefile

I'm trying to learn how to use makefiles, and this is my attempt at making a makefile that compiles source files in a source directory (src/) into object files that are created in a bin directory.

```
##########################################
#           Editable options             #
##########################################

# Compiler options
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
EXECUTABLE_NAME=testes

# Folders
SRC=src
BIN=bin
OBJ=$(BIN)/obj

# Files
SOURCE_FILES=\
    main.cpp \
    test.cpp

##########################################
#    Don't touch anything below this     #
##########################################
OBJECT_FILES=$(addprefix $(OBJ)/, $(SOURCE_FILES:.cpp=.o))

build: create_directories create_executable
    @echo "Build successful!"

create_executable: create_objects
    @$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECT_FILES) -o $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
    @echo "Created executable."

create_objects: $(SOURCE_FILES)
    @echo "Created objects."

create_directories: 
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ)

%.cpp:
    @echo "Compiling "$@
    @$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -c $(SRC)/$@ -o $(OBJ)/$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$@)

clean:
    @rm -r -f $(BIN)
```

This makefile works, I just want to make sure I'm doing everything correctly.  Any changes you guys would suggest?

Comment: For novices, I don't recommend suppressing the echoing of commands and printing the progress reports manually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not using the make system properly.  As a result, **it will always relink the executable**, even when everything is already up to date.  On the other hand, it might **fail to recompile some source files into object files.**

When you run `make`…

- It will try to create the `build` target.  No file named `build` exists, so…

  - It will try to create the prerequisites of `build`, namely `create_directories` and `create_executable`, neither of which are names of existing files.

    - In an attempt to create a file called `create_directories`, it runs `mkdir -p $(OBJ)`.
    - For `create_executable`, it needs to rebuild `create_objects`.

      - For `create_objects`, it just verifies that all of the source files are present.

        - For any of the `$(SOURCE_FILES)` that is missing, it "creates" it using the `%.cpp:` rule, which *actually tries to compile the missing .cpp* into a .o.
        - Once all of the `$(SOURCE_FILES)` are present, it echoes `"Created objects."`.  That's a false claim due to the error above.

      Having thus falsely satisfied the prerequisites for `create_executable`, it proceeds to attempt to link the executable, even if any of the `$(OBJECT_FILES)` is missing.

The main remedy is to specify real targets and real dependencies, rather than phony labels like `create_executable`.

Here is how I would write it.  Other than the major problems cited above, I have also noted many minor issues in the comments.

```
#########################################################
# Replacing everything that you told me not to touch... #
#########################################################
EXECUTABLE_FILES = $(EXECUTABLE_NAME:%=$(BIN)/%)
OBJECT_FILES     = $(SOURCE_FILES:%.cpp=$(OBJ)/%.o)
# ^^^ A more succinct expression for $(OBJECT_FILES), using
#     http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs

build: $(EXECUTABLE_FILES)

clean:
    rm -r -f $(BIN)
    @# ^^^ I don't recommend suppressing the echoing of the command using @

# http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets
.PHONY: build clean

$(EXECUTABLE_FILES): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    @$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
    @# ^^^ http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables
    @echo "Build successful!"

# http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern
$(OBJECT_FILES): $(OBJ)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo Compiling $<
    @# ^^^ Your terminology is weird: you "compile a .cpp file" to create a .o file.
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @# ^^^ http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_0024_0028_0040D_0029
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
    @# ^^^ Use $(CFLAGS), not $(LDFLAGS), when compiling.
```

Comment: Thanks, I think my errors were because of a complete misunderstanding of what the main idea of makefiles was.  This made them a lot clearer to me.

Also, in the $(EXECUTABLE_FILES) target, I found that I was getting errors about undefined functions.  I changed the $< to $^ in that target, would that be a valid approach to solving the problem?

Comment: I stand corrected! `$^` is right. `$+` might be even more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for you help, you really helped illuminate me on this subject!

Comment: @hopeless_nerd, your first comment to this answer got me hooked. One of the most important insights to gain about makefiles, is that the point of using them is to not have to recompile all code in all files every time if you have made just a minor change in _one_ file while all the other files remain unchanged. This also explains why you cannot simply replace a `makefile` by some shell script which does not support managing dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Using `@` to hide the build commands can make it harder to debug failing builds (hiding non-build commands such as `echo` is fine).

The most visible project that does this is the Linux kernel, and it is careful to provide an opt-out (by setting `KBUILD_VERBOSE`, if I remember correctly) so that the normal output is available when necessary.

You'll also want normal output when you use `make -n` to preview what commands will run.

We're not even consistent with the use of progress `echo` commands - some run before the build commands, and some afterwards.

---

The makefile is missing the usual `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` and `.PHONY:` targets.

---

This rule doesn't do what it claims:

> ```
> create_objects: $(SOURCE_FILES)
>     @echo "Created objects."
> ```

We probably want Make to just create objects as needed, by making the executable program depend on the specific object files it needs.

To this end, we should just define a list of object files - the list of source files is used only to generate this list, so that's redundant.

We can copy our build rules from the standard built-in rules (examine using `make -f /dev/null --print-data-base | grep -Fw -e COMPILE.cc -e LINK.cc`):

```
OBJECTS += main.o
OBJECTS += test.o

OBJECT_FILES=$(addprefix $(OBJ)/, $(OBJECTS))

$(OBJ)/%o: %.cpp:
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME): $(OBJECT_FILES)
        $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

We could avoid writing our own rules if we just build in the current working directory (which could be a build directory parallel to the source, if we use `VPATH` to locate the sources).

It helps if one of the object files is named the same as the executable (with `.o` added, of course), so that Make can use the built-in rules for linking.

---

Object files should also depend on any headers included by the source files.  We can get GCC to help with this, by using `-MMD` to create dependency files for Make, which can then be `include`d into the Makefile if they exist.

---

In a parallel build, these two dependencies will execute together:

> ```
> build: create_directories create_executable
> ```

That means that `create_executable` can start before the directories are created.  The rules that depend on directories existing need to ensure they are present, rather than assuming some other rule has done that.

---

Modified Makefile
I've retained the subdirectories for build products, although I don't recommend them.

```
##########################################
#           Editable options             #
##########################################

EXECUTABLE_NAME = testes

# Files
OBJECTS += main.o
OBJECTS += test.o

# Directories
SRC = src
BIN = bin
OBJ = $(BIN)/obj

# Compiler options
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
CXXFLAGS += -Wextra
CXXFLAGS += -MMD

##########################################
#    Don't touch anything below this     #
##########################################
OBJECT_FILES=$(addprefix $(OBJ)/, $(OBJECTS))

build: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
    @echo "Build successful!"

create_directories:
    @test -d $(OBJ) || mkdir -v $(OBJ)

$(OBJ)/%o: %.cpp:
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

$(OBJ)/%o: create_directories

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE_NAME): $(OBJECT_FILES)
        $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

-include($(OBJ)/*.d)

clean:
    @(RM) -r $(BIN)

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
.PHONY: build clean create_directories
```